# Pandas: Multiple date formats in one column

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I have two date formats in one Pandas series (column) that need to be standardized into one format (mmm dd & mm/dd/YY)

**Date**

Jan 3

Jan 2

Jan 1

12/31/19

12/30/19

12/29/19

Even Excel won't recognize the mmm dd format as a date format. I can change the mmm to a fully-spelled out month using str.replace:

df['Date'] = df['Date'].str.replace('Jan', 'January', regex=True)

But how do I add the current year? How do I then convert January 1, 2020 to 01/01/20?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's in a data frame use this:

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import pandas as pd

for i in range(len(df['Date'])):
    df['Date'][i] = parse(df['Date'][i])
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).dt.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")
```

Comment: Thank you. The df['Date'] series is a datetime64[ns] type. I converted it to a string first: df['Date'] = df['Date'].astype(str) before running your code. Once I did, I got this error: <ipython-input-211-4d50620ed530>:5: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  df['Date'][i] = parse(df['Date'][i])

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried the parse()

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime

def clean_date(text):
  datetimestr = parse(text)
  text = datetime.strptime(datetimestr, '%Y%m%d')
  return text

df['Date'] = df['Date'].apply(clean_date)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
```

Comment: I get this error: Parser must be a string or character stream, not Series.                                        I need to parse an entire Pandas series, but really only the rows in the wrong date format.

Comment: Check the answer now

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution (needed to use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html)):

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
```